# How to denoise night scenes in blender?

Tags: rendering, shaders, light, denoise, noise-reduction

Pls help, I've been struggling to reduce noise in this scene and noise ruins all well-done textures and emission materials. Funnel lights are points along with sphere emitters to imitate lamps. Even after 300 samples, it's like yuk.

S.O.S Pls help...

Render Preview:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use branched path tracing.
It got my work right.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you can use a newer version of Blender, there's denoising feature. It is so easy to use, you only need to check a checkbox. Here's where you can find it on Blender 2.93:

[image]